# The system cannot find the file specified Exception in Process Start

Tags: c#, .net, exception, process

I am having some exception in starting a process from C#
Following is the code

```
Process myProcess = new Process();  
try  
{  
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;  
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe C:\\Users\\Karthick\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\5aau1orm.txt";  
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;  
    myProcess.Start();  
}  
catch (Exception e)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);  
}
```

And sometimes I get the exception "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" if useShellExecute is set to false

Any Ideas as to why this is not coming out correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @SLaks, this is the appropriate way
let the default application (in your case mapped to the .txt extension) open the file

```
Process.Start("test.txt");
```

But if you prefer to open text files only in Notepad and not in other default Text Editor

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe", "text.txt");
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works exactly. I wanted only notepad to open the application

Answer (score 3):

You can't put an entire commandline in the `FileName` property.

Instead, you should just `Start` the txt file, which will open in the user's default editor:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Karthick\AppData\Local\Temp\5aau1orm.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute `c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe C:\\Users\\Karthick\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\5aau1orm.txt`. If you aren't using a shell, it will be interpreted literally. If you use the shell, the shell will take care of the argument parsing.

Use the `ProcessStartInfo.Arguements` property to supply arguments instead.

Answer (score 0):

FileName property dosen't take command line type syntax. What you have specified is for command line.

Since its only a **`.txt`** file you can use [**Process.Start()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Method with full file path. It will automatically search for the respective **default program** to open the file.